# What part of algebra can I use to describe linked curves?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves

Can anybody tell me what is the algebraic structure of linked curves in 3D space?

Can their linking number be described using a vector space? Or does it require some other structure such as a group, ring ,etc. I am strictly interested in describing *the linking number*, preferably with a vector space which would allow me to work with matrices.

For example in the image below, curve 1 is linked once with 2, 3 is linked once with 4 which is linked once with 5. Curve 6 is not linked with any other curve but is self-intersecting having the linking number 3 (if I'm not mistaking). I am interested in describing much more complicated structures than this and I really can't visualize them when curves intermingle each other in complicated ways.

[image]

I would like a little guidance, as I can do the grunt work myself. If possible, an online reference recommendation with a gentle introduction to the subject would much appreciated.

Comment: This question seems to be rather vague. What do you mean by "the algebraic structure of linked curves in 3D space"?

Comment: There really isn't a "linking number" of a single curve like 6, although given any diagram like that, you can construct a second curve by displacing the given curve upwards in the direction of the page, with a convention about which one is "on top" when they cross, and then there is a linking number of the original and the displaced curve, which is sometimes called the self-linking-number of the original curve. Maybe you'd be interested in the link group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_group) of your link? The ordinary linking number of two linked curves does arise from their link group.

Answer (score 2):

[Racks and quandles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles) are associated with knot theory. In fact, it does not make any sense at all to mention [linking number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number) without talking about [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory).

You *have* checked out knot theory, right?  There are invariants of knots that you can find, and racks and quandles are supposed to be used in relation to them.